# Image on http url shows old image instead of updated image

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am loading image from http url inside  tag.
However, I have updated the image from backend but on mobile device I am not able to see updated image.
It's always showing me the old image.

Comment: can you provide your code for more reference?

Comment: <ImageBackground style={{flex:1}}
            source={{uri:this.state.backgroundImage}}
            resizeMode={'cover'}>
              <View style={{flex: 0.2}}> 
              <Text></Text>
              </View>
              <View style={{flex: 0.8, alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center', padding: 16}}>
                <ScrollView >
                  <HTML html={this.state.passcodesview} />
                </ScrollView>
              </View>
            </ImageBackground>

Comment: In the <ImageBackground /> i am loading the image form uri, which is showing me old image.

Comment: Can someone help me out with this issue. I am trying this from very long time.

Comment: It may not be a front end library problem. Browsers will cache the static resources based on it's cache lifetime.

Comment: I am using react-native and running this on android device. However for some device it is working perfectly but for some device it is still displaying older images.

Comment: still waiting for someone to reply.

Answer (score 1):

When serving the image from backend, add a timestamp attribute to the image url as a query param, i.e `<image_url>?t=12233554`. 
You can fine-tune this method more - 
like when storing the image, put the timestamp for that time only as a query param, and directly serve the file to the user.